# FORM VALIDTION difficulty

Tags: html, jsp

I applied validation IN THIS JSP PAGE. If I leave username/password empty, I will be prompted to enter those to fields, but the PROBLEM is that after I press OK on validation prompt,the page goes to 2_control.jsp.I WANT IT TO GO TO THE NEXT PAGE ONLY IF the validation thing is ok,not otherwise.plz hlp.What change should i make?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validLogin(){
if (document.form.userName.value == ""){
alert ( "Please enter Login Name." );
document.loginform.userName.focus();
return false;
}
if (document.form.password.value == ""){
alert ( "Please enter password." );
document.userform.password.focus();
return false;
}
alert ( "Welcome User" );
return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="2_control.jsp" onsubmit="return validLogin();">
<table width="250px" border=0 style="background-color:ffeeff;">
<tr><td colspan=2 align="center" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20pt;" align="center">User Login</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:12pt;" align="center">Login Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="userName" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:12pt;" align="center">Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `document.userform.password.focus();`  to `document.form.userName.focus();`

Change only form name when you focus on text box.. userform is wrong so your validation is not work..

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        function validLogin(){
            if (document.form.userName.value == ""){
                alert ( "Please enter Login Name." );
                document.form.userName.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.form.password.value == ""){
                alert ( "Please enter password." );
                document.form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Replace this script tag...
You do small mistake in writing form name..